# Extract values from a text file for a multiline pattern which has three fields

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

How to extract values from a text file for a multiline pattern which has three fields "ID", "First name" and "Last name"?

Extract only the pattern where the "ID" field has 9 digits with two spaces in there and the "First name" field not equal to "XXXXX".
Remove the two spaces in the "ID" field.
Remove the "Gender" field in the "First name" line.

e.g.
Input:

```
ID : 200 000 000
Address: Test
First name: XXXXX   Gender: M
Last name: YYYYY

ID : 123 456 789
Address: Anywhere 1
First name: Albert   Gender: M
Last name: Au

ID : YYY YYY YYY
ID : ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ

ID : 100 000 000
Address: Anywhere 2
First name: Priscilla   Gender: F
Last name: Chan

ID : QQQ ZZZ ZZZ
Address: Test 2
First name: XXXXX   Gender: M
Last name: ZZZZZ
```

Output:

```
ID : 123456789
First name: Albert
Last name: Au

ID : 100000000
First name: Priscilla
Last name: Chan
```

I modified αғsнιη's original command below to:

`awk -v RS='' -F'\n|: *' '{ bkup=$0 } gsub("Address:", "", bkup) && gsub("Gender:", "", bkup) && gsub($4, "", bkup) && gsub(" ", "", $2)==2 && $2+0==$2 && $6 !~ /^XXXXX  *Gender$/ { print bkup }' infile.txt`

Output:

```
ID : 123 456 789

First name: Albert    M
Last name: Au
ID : 100 000 000

First name: Priscilla    F
Last name: Chan
```

I modified αғsнιη's improved command below to:

`awk -v RS='' -F'\n|: *' '{ bkup=$0; id=$2; gsub(/\nAddress[^\n]*\n| *Gender *: *[MF]\n/, "\n", bkup) } gsub(" ", "", $2)==2 && $2+0==$2 &&  gsub(id, $2, bkup) && $6 !~ /^XXXXX *Gender$/ { print bkup }' infile.txt`

Output as expected:

```
ID : 123456789
First name: Albert
Last name: Au
ID : 100000000
First name: Priscilla
Last name: Chan
```

How to get the expected output with sed?

If the input have more spaces and extra characters in the ID field, how to get the expected output?
e.g.

Input:

```
ID      : 200 000 000   Status : 1
Address: Test
First name: XXXXX   Gender: M
Last name: YYYYY

ID      : 123 456 789   Status : 2
Address: Anywhere 1
First name: Albert   Gender: M
Last name: Au

ID      : YYY YYY YYY   Status : _
ID      : ZZZ ZZZ ZZZ   Status : _

ID      : 100 000 000   Status : 3   XYZ
Address: Anywhere 2
First name: Priscilla   Gender: F
Last name: Chan

ID      : QQQ ZZZ ZZZ   Status : 4
Address: Test 2
First name: XXXXX   Gender: M
Last name: ZZZZZ
```

I modified nezabudka's solution below to:

`sed -nr '/ID      : ([0-9]{3} ){2}[0-9]{3}/!b s/\s//3g :1;N;/Last name/!b1 /First name: XXXXX/!s/(Gender|Status|\nAddress)[^\n]*//gp ' infile2.txt`

Output:

```
ID  :123456789
First name: Albert
Last name: Au
ID  :100000000
First name: Priscilla
Last name: Chan
```

Expected output - the ID field is modified to the same format as the First name field:

```
ID: 123456789
First name: Albert
Last name: Au
ID: 100000000
First name: Priscilla
Last name: Chan
```

Comment: Is there a question? All I see is a command. Please remember: we don't work for you, and we are not a free script-writing service. We are here to _help_ you do your work not just do it for you. So which part of this is giving you problems? What do you have so far? Please [edit] your question and show us what you have tried and how it failed so we don't repeat the same work and errors.

Comment: Please edit your question with an exmple of what you want as input and output

Comment: @francoisP It seems like both input and expected output was part of the question from the start.

Comment: Yes, both input and expected output was part of the question from the start.  I am glad that αғsнιη provided a command for me to adjust to get my desired output, I will try as a practice and post my result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -nr '/ID : ([0-9]{3} ){2}[0-9]{3}/!b
 s/\s//3g
 :1;N;/Last name/!b1
 /First name: XXXXX/!s/(Gender|\nAddress)[^\n]*//gp
' file
```

```
ID : 123456789
First name: Albert   
Last name: Au
ID : 100000000
First name: Priscilla   
Last name: Chan
```

Comment: @ nezabudka Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 4):

OP resolved his question after giving him/her some hints, and now I'm posting complete command and showing that how that could be simplified as following ([click here](/posts/657383/revisions) to see revision history) including adding how to verify length of ID value is 9digits (we only validate length of integer numbers):

```
awk -v RS= -F'\n|: *' '{ id=$2; gsub(/\nAddress[^\n]*\n| *Gender *: *[MF]\n/, "\n") }
    gsub(" ", "", id)==2 &&
    id+0==id && length(id)==9 &&
    $4 !="XXXXX" && sub($2, id) &&
    $0=(++n>1?ORS:"") $0
' infile
```

Output is:

```
ID : 123456789
First name: Albert
Last name: Au

ID : 100000000
First name: Priscilla
Last name: Chan
```

---

Here we are checking with `gsub(" ", "", id)==2`, if there was only two space characters in the value of ID key (by replacing them with empty string we will remove those spaces too as requested);

then we checks if that is number `id+0==id` (by adding 0 it forces awk to do string to integer conversation and then it checks if converted value is equal to itself or not);

next we are checking that *`First name`* has value other than `XXXXX` with `$4 != "XXXXX"`;

and later we swap modified `id` value with `$2` (spaces removed); if all these conditions were evaluated to true, that record will be printed.

Comment: I am glad that you provided a command for me to adjust to get my desired output, I will try as a practice and post my result.

Comment: awk -v RS='' -F'\n|: *' '{ bkup=$0 } gsub("Address:", "", bkup) && gsub("Gender:", "", bkup) && gsub($4, "", bkup) && gsub(" ", "", $2)==2 && $2+0==$2 && $6 !~ /^XXXXX  *Gender$/ { print bkup }' infile.txt

Comment: Output is as follows. How to improve the command? ID : 123 456 789

First name: Albert    M
Last name: Au
ID : 100 000 000

First name: Priscilla    F
Last name: Chan

Comment: @albertkao9 nice job! improved command would be to call one gsub() for all you did, like `awk -v RS='' -F'\n|: *' '{ bkup=$0; gsub(/\nAddress[^\n]*\n| *Gender *: *[MF]\n/, "\n", bkup) } gsub(" ", "", $2)==2 && $2+0==$2 && $6 !~ /^XXXXX *Gender$/ { print bkup }' infile.txt`; also please edit your question and add these as you tried :   )

Comment: @ αғsнιη Thank you very much for your awk command!!! I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote. I edited my question and added these as I tried.

Comment: @albertkao9 it's praiseworthy that seeing you how you did and you wrote the command to get your expected output! you are good! I already upvote your question because of your insist on solving your own problem really thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using `GNU sed` with extended regex option `-E` we can do as follows.
The lines are appended to hold space until we meet an empty line or the last line. At which point we inspect the hold space and print after the validation checks pass.

```
sed -En '
  /^$/!{H;$!d;}
  g
  /\nID :( [0-9]{3}){3}\n/!bx
  /\nFirst name: X{5} /bx
  s/\nAddress:[^\n]*//
  s/(\nFirst name: [^\n]+)Gender:[^\n]*/\1/;ta
  :a
    s/(\nID : ([0-9]{3}){1,2}) /\1/
  ta
  p;:x;z;x
' file

ID : 123456789
First name: Albert   
Last name: Au

ID : 100000000
First name: Priscilla   
Last name: Chan
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

```
mlr --prepipe 'sed "s/Gender/\n&/"' --xtab --ps ':' --ops ': ' clean-whitespace \
  then filter '${ID} =~ "[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{3}" && ${First name} != "XXXXX"' \
  then put '${ID} = gsub(${ID}," ","")' \
  then cut -x -f Address,Gender Input
ID: 123456789
First name: Albert
Last name: Au

ID: 100000000
First name: Priscilla
Last name: Chan
```

Note that this removes trailing whitespace from the `ID`  field name; if that's not acceptable then either omit the `clean-whitespace` and use `strip({First name})` in the filter, or restore the original name by chaining `rename ID,"ID "`.

Comment: I do not know mlr.   I know a little about awk and sed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -00ne 's/\s+Gender:.*//;
              print if s/ID : (\d{3}) (\d{3}) (\d{3})/ID : $1$2$3/ 
                       && ! m/First name: XXXXX\b/' input.txt  
ID : 123456789
Address: Anywhere 1
First name: Albert
Last name: Au

ID : 100000000
Address: Anywhere 2
First name: Priscilla
Last name: Chan
```

The `-00` tells `perl` to read the input in paragraph mode - i.e. records are separated by one or more empty lines.